# i18n translation is not rendering in angular using nx MFE

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx, mfe

I created new micro front end it is running properly but in all application translation is not loading i have tried with the nx and created the shared asset module but not able to resolve.

I want to load translation properly in shell app and in newly created MFE.